# Using Javascript RegEx

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm new to javascript regular expression..

this is my problem:

```
http://example/uploads/files/full/images/image.png
```

I just want to get the `uploads/files/full/images/image.png`

How can I do it using regex ?

Help anyone.. thanks..

Comment: [regexpal.com](http://regexpal.com) is a really useful site for testing out javascript regular expressions/working your way through questions like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var someString = "http://example/uploads/files/full/images/image.png";
var path = someString.match(/https?:\/\/example\/(.+)$/)[1];
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Squeegy/QwHsC/

```
// matches http or https
https?

// matches :// since you have to escape slashes
:\/\/

// matches the domain name
example/

// captures the path all the way to the end of the string
(.+)$
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use a more comprehensive library for this sort of thing in future (ie rather than constructing/requesting specific regexes as you need them), you could take a look at something like this:

http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/parseuri

In which case,

```
parseUri("http://example/uploads/files/full/images/image.png").path
```

would return

```
uploads/files/full/images/image.png
```

Comment: Parsing a URL is better than regex hacking a URL, when possible.

Comment: @AlexWayne Yes I agree... but I guess you get the green tick because you answered the specific question as asked! ;-)  Must admit I'd probably hack out a regex rather than go out of my way to incorporate a new lib, if it were a one-off where I knew the format of the URL wouldn't change etc...